# Moving a DIV by scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I'm creating a jQuery scrollbar which scrolls the content in a <div>. It's something like [jQuery ScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

I've come to the point where I need to move the scroll button. My question is: what is the best way to do it without any UI plugin? So when the user clicks on the scroll button it can be moved vertically in its parent container with a mousedown event. How could I do that?

Comment: i know you wrote you don't want to use a ui plugin but why? ui-draggable seems like exactly what you'd need? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: That's a requirement from my customer. The script must be a "lightweight", easy configurable, standalone script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a starting point, hope that's what you're after:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.slider').slider();
});

$.fn.slider = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.css('top', 0);
        var dragging = false;
        var startY = 0;
        var startT = 0;
        $el.mousedown(function(ev) {
            dragging = true;
            startY = ev.clientY;
            startT = $el.css('top');
        });
        $(window).mousemove(function(ev) {
            if (dragging) {
                // calculate new top
                var newTop = parseInt(startT) + (ev.clientY - startY);
                
                //stay in parent
                var maxTop =  $el.parent().height()-$el.height();          
                newTop = newTop<0?0:newTop>maxTop?maxTop:newTop;
                $el.css('top', newTop );
            }
        }).mouseup(function() {
            dragging = false;
        });
    });
}
```

```css
.container{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
}
.slider{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background:green; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slider" />
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider" />
</div>
```

Comment: That is AWESOME!  Above and beyond! You also showed how to turn it into a jQuery reusable function with complementary CSS classes for easy re-usability.  I extended it to work in both X and Y directions and doing so required me to add a top: 0, and left: 0 to the slider class in CSS, because left defaulted to "auto" and math couldn't be done with it so it didn't work until I did that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

I developed a right nav dock style item with just plain javascript. 
Here is the link:

https://github.com/developerDoug/HtmlJavascriptDockInVS2010

Using a ui plugin would be best if you can convince your customer to do so. If not, what you'll need to focus on is hanling mousedown or something similar to that to be noticed that moving has began. The there methods to focus on are: mousedown, mousemove, mouseup.

For example, if on some div, you detect mousedown, you could call a function which basically would be your beginDrag, get x y coordinates, keep a reference to the start coordinates, attachEvent (if IE), addEventListener (for all other browsers).

ex:

```
// keep reference to drag div
_dragObj = new Object();

$("myDragDiv").mousedown(function(e) {
    dragBegin(e);
}

function dragBegin(e) {

    _dragObj = document.getElementById('myDragDiv');

    var x, y;

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        x = window.event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft + document.body.scrollLeft;
        y = window.event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop;
    } else {
        x = e.clientX + window.scrollX;
        y = e.clientY + window.scrollY;
    }

    _dragObj.cursorStartX = x;
    _dragObj.cursorStartY = y;

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        document.attachEvent("onmousemove", dragContinue);
        document.attachEvent("onmouseup", dragEnd);
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragContinue, true);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, true);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function dragContinue(e) {
    var x, y;

    var isIE = _browser.isIE;
    var isWebKitBased = _browser.isWebKitBased;

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        x = window.event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft + document.body.scrollLeft;
        y = window.event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop;
    } else {
        x = e.clientX + window.scrollX;
        y = e.clientY + window.scrollY;
    }

    var distance = x - _dragObj.cursorStartX;

    distance = Math.abs(distance);

    // or top, bottom, right
    _dragObj.elNode.style.left = (_dragObj.elStartLeft + x - _dragObj.cursorStartX) + "px";

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function dragEnd() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        document.detachEvent("onmousemove", dragContinue);
        document.detachEvent("onmouseup", dragEnd);
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", dragContinue, true);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: note: i took my example, and did my best to tailor it toward you example. tweaks maybe needed. :)

Comment: +1 since the asker obviously doesn't even care enough to respond