# How does scrolltop () jquery method work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen scrolltop () function in jquery documentation and I want to know how this function manages to get scrolled pixels.What parameters the function gets to calculate content that is not displayed above the scrollable area?

Comment: jQuery is open source... http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.scrollTop

Comment: Thanks.Can you explain me what the function does?I am not so expert with jquery

Answer (score -1):

scrolltop() refers to the amount that the user has scrolled down, in a scroll-able element. If the user is scrolled right to the top, the scrolltop will return "0".

Regards, hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answare:)I know what the function does but I want to know how it does what it does:)

Comment: The function propaply gets the scroll element height and the amount each mouse scroll is supposed to scroll down in pixels, and the rest is pretty straight forward.

Comment: It's not so easy because users could scroll down clicking on the scrollbar and going down and up.In that case there are not established pixel.Do you agree?

Comment: Well, I see what you mean but here is an example of someone moving a element onmousedown and with mouse position. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KQpe9/)[link] Works with same principal. Do you agree?

Comment: Here is an example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610388/moving-a-div-with-mouse)

Comment: So you think that ScrollTop method is a combination of various events?

Comment: Well yes, the mouse scroll event and the mouse drag event.

Comment: A function like this needs to combine all the possible event that could scroll.I have thought to something like this:take the position of the first child of the scrollable element and on scroll see its position.Then make a comparison between the position of scrollable div and the position of its first child to see how many pixels are been scrolled.

Comment: That could work, but what if the first child is not the topmost child (from top of viewport or parent) of the scroll-able element? You would propably have to compare the positions of all of the children to see who is the topmost element. Then you can go on from there.

Comment: Yes,it could be a solution:)Or we can put a child in scrollable div on scroll and take his position:)

Comment: Yes, if you are worried about time exhaustive to sort through all the elements that could be the better problem. Best of luck to you

Comment: sort all children is not a problem.I put the reference son like first child of the scrollable div and like brother of all the others.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a example to show an "back to top" icon on web page, if users scroll down the window over 500 px. The scrollTop function can get the pixels user scrolled. Hope it helps!

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
            $("#totopIcon").css( "display", "block" );
        } else {
            $("#totopIcon").css( "display", "none" );
        }

    });
```